# Different ways of selecting columns inside function resulting in different results, why?

Tags: r

I have written a short function to clean some dataframes that I have in a list. When selecting columns using the df[,1] method, my function doesn't work. However when I select using df$Column it does. Why is this?

```
columns_1 <- function(x) {
  x[,1] <- dmy_hm(x[,1])
  x[,2] <- NULL
  x[,3] <- as.numeric(x[,3])
  x[,4] <- NULL
  return(x)
}

MS_ <- lapply(MS_, columns_1)


columns_2 <- function(x) {
  x$DateTime <- dmy_hm(x$DateTime)
  x$LogSeconds <- NULL
  x$Pressure <- as.numeric(x$Pressure)
  x$Temperature <- NULL
  return(x)
}

MS_ <- lapply(MS_, columns_2)
```

The function columns_2 produces the desired results (all dataframes in list are cleaned). columns_1 returns the error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a `list` of `data.frame`s  Would that be a `matrix` because `$` extraction doesn't work with `matrices`.  Please check the `str(MS_[[1]])`

Comment: Be careful with the numeric indexing. When you do `x[,2] <- NULL`, the indexing changes and what was before the third column becomes the second column. This might be the issue here. You don't have the problem if you call your columns by name of course.

Answer (score 2):

The issue would be that the assignment was carried out after the first run and here some columns were lost.

```
library(lubridate)
MS_ <- lapply(MS_, columns_1)
```

Instead, it can be done by assigning to a different object

```
MS2_ <- lapply(MS_, columns_1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(DateTime = format(Sys.Date() + 1:5, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
    LogSeconds = 1:5, 
    Pressure = rnorm(5), Temperature = rnorm(5, 25),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
MS_ <- list(df1, df1)
```